# JSOn object not deserializing properly in wcf webservice side

Tags: c#, ios, json, web-services, wcf

I am working on iOS project and  sending the Json string to backend through wcf webservice, Its working successfully for many users but for some users backend getting incomplete json string.

Code for generating Json string

```
NSData *data = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:EmployeeDetails options:0 error:nil];
    NSString *JsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data
                                                 encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

And Attaching the json string with request by below code

```
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setHTTPBody:[jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

EmployeeDetails is NSMutableDictionary with employee details.

And

Here is successful Json string deserialized from BackEnd

```
{"FirstName":"Donald","LastCBPaymentType":6,"AcceptEmail":true,"CellPhone":"321-300-6874","Position":"3","CarrierNum":"4","EmpNum":"96874"}
```

And Incomplete Json string

```
{"FirstName":"roset","LastCBPaymentType":6,"AcceptEmail":true,"CellPhone":"321-300-6874","Position":"3","CarrierNum":"4","EmpNum":"98799
```

The incomplete json string occuring in backend for some user.

Any one can help to solve this issue ?

Comment: what the result you get here `EmployeeDetails`

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik we are getting incomplete data({"FirstName":"roset","LastCBPaymentType":6,"AcceptEmail":true,"CellPhone":"321-300-6874","Position":"3","CarrierNum":"4","EmpNum":"9879), 
Its only happening for some users

Comment: it means you got the response from server but  irrrgeular formart, correct

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik: No, we sent the data from ios app to server and server getting the incomplete json data(server side).

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik: Is this situation will come due to network traffic ?

Comment: r u sure it occurs networks  traffic

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik : I am not sure. This issue only occurred for some users, and remaining 7000 users data captured perfectly from backend. The issue is with capturing data from backend

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120860/discussion-between-sivaprasad-km-and-anbu-karthik).

Comment: you have to be sure that you are sending the correct json first from IOS , try use Fiddler or Postman, an see what happen, if the issue still exists, then the problem will be the server,

Answer (score 1):

Well, I'd say [TomSwift](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39047833/6165597) is on the right track... It's apparent that the broken JSON is simply missing "} from the end of the string. That does indeed look like something being sanitised by a regex...
You really should find the source of the problem; But for a quick and dirty fix *while you figure it out*, you could just run your own regex on the JSON you receive and if it doesn't end with a "}, just add it... First do something like: '/"[0-9]+$/' (to check if there is an open numeric string at the end, if there is, you close it by adding " ) then check if '/}$/' (if } is the last char, if it isn't: add it).

Remember, the above would only be a temporary fix (as it is somewhat heavy and not really that pretty), but I could imagine myself being forced to do something like this, simply because of time constraints. If the issue is actually coming from within the API, you could tell the creators about it and use something like that fix above while they fixed it.

PS. If anyone does choose to use a fix like the above, please please please, for the love of all that you hold holy, leave a comment in the code explaining **why you did it** (as opposed to telling us **what** you did...).

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem in PHP/CodeIgniter recently and the problem was that the JSON was being "sanitized" via some overly ambitious regular expressions before it arrived to my handler.   Perhaps there's some similar sanitization that happens in WCF?

Things I would try:

1. Using [Charles Proxy](https://www.charlesproxy.com) to confirm that the request (POST?) is actually sending the full body as you expect.
2. Try Content-Type application/json instead.